# how to set custom height of item for flutter gridview.count

Tags: flutter

I am new in Flutter and i want to make a GridView in flutter where Gridview items height can be customized by me and one more thing can someone please explain me how childAspectRatio works in GridView.count .

Comment: For an explanation you should take a look to the official documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists. If you have a failing implementation share your code and we'll help you

Comment: I have seen the code on the link given but i am unable to set height of GridView item .